# how to rerun init:funtion() in require.js when new dom elements are loaded

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a tweeter like app where i use init to bind mouseover to loaded elements but when new elements are loaded , new mouseover is not binded to the new elements

Comment: Edit your question accordingly. Also show us some HTML around .truncate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite your init. Attach event to parent and manipulate event.target.